# Commenting namespaces doesn't affect the ToString() method

Tags: c#

Today someone showed me a code snippet and I am wondering how its working:

```
//using System;
//using System.Collections.Generic;
//using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Test
    {
        int i = 0;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test obj = new Test();
            obj.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

My question is if we have commented the above namespaces, how is the `ToString()` method still associated to the object `obj`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Every class in C# inherits Object class, in which ToString is defined

Comment: Ok I get it, but can you please tell me how this kind of inheritance takes place, when i have commented all the namespaces which are required by CLR. If not then what association these namespaces create.

Comment: When you create your class Test, CLR automatically inherits it from Object, no namaspaces are required for this.